# Resolving the divide between logic and emotion, and their presence in causality

Tags: logic, causality, emotions

I've always questioned the dissension between logic and emotion. Whether it is right to disassociate emotion as this is seemingly logical, or promote the wellness of emotion.

I'm, whether wise or naive, only interested in the extremity, large commitment to one and at my point in life this details my commitment to expanding knowledge, working to cultivate my understanding of the world or living a healthy social life, disregarding time and it's intimidation.
But then again I'm not looking for simple life advice.

In the past few years I've become enraptured in physics, finding beauty in the math and satisfaction in the answers, which guide my curiosity. And in this interest I've found myself wanting to contend in the hierarchy.

But questioning whether this commitment is fundamental, always dismissing it to the idea that knowledge, pure knowledge of any kind is good.

The question is whether commitment to knowledge or life is the most logical, and why I request for this answer as both are fufilling is unknown.

And as most may see in this passage I've shifted focus and maybe even contradicted my own statements, or resolved my own questions. 
But the conclusion I've always come to is 
"Either works"
Where with no inherent meaning in life, both are satisfactory. " how I see the logic contradictory in choice. 
And this conclusion is painfully toxic to my time.

•Do you have any ideas or knowledge that can aid on resolving this, and while it is easy to dismiss the idea of forcing an answer out of this absurd, I passionately seek resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer here is that there simply is no such division.  The clarity that one experiences when one is sure of one's logic *is an emotion*.  And as medical/psychiatric observations like those of [Antonio Dimasio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antonio_Damasio) shows, logic, deprived of emotion quite clearly fails to remain logical.

There is not a separation here, and these two do not even lie at opposite extremes on some continuum.  The glorious 'Aha' feeling of correctly reasoning something out can, be as intense as fear or anger.  Nietzsche's 'gaiety' and 'cheer' were for him evidence of his own truthfulness to himself.  All his logic was validated by the power of the feelings that it captured.

Comment: I'd agree with Jobermark's comment. I find that the female of the species is prone to dismiss logic as being inferior to intuition and emotion but I see need for opposition between them. As usual it's all about balance. Any argument for emotion over logic would have to depend on logic and not emotion.